# Java REST Spring 3.2.3 apache cxf 2.7.5 produces XML OK but cant produce JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, cxf

About **my config :**

`Spring 3.2.3 (with java class configuration`) and

```
apache cxf 2.7.5
```

I try to get `spring/cxf` working but i cant produce `JSON data.`

I got this **error** `"No message body writer has been found for response class Photo."`

When i switch from `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` it works! any idea to solve my problem ?

In both case the `wadl` is working (`localhost/photoservice-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/rest/photoservice?_wadl`)

The skeleton of this very basic project is here : https://github.com/wooxorg/sandbox

```
package org.woox.photoservice.webservice;  
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.woox.photoservice.model.Photo;
import org.woox.photoservice.service.PhotoServiceImpl;

@Path("/photo")
public class PhotoServiceWS {

    @Inject
    private PhotoServiceImpl photoService;

    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    public Photo getPhoto() {
        return photoService.getPhoto();
    }
}


package org.woox.photoservice.service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.woox.photoservice.model.Photo;

@Service
public class PhotoServiceImpl  {

    public Photo getPhoto() {
        Photo myPhoto = new Photo();
        myPhoto.setTitle("title");
        return myPhoto;
    }

}

package org.woox.photoservice.model;
public class Photo {

    private String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess you don't have the serializers you need in your class path. Add these `jaxkson-core-asl`, `jackson-mapper-asl` and `jackson-jaxrs` to your classpath and I believe this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much when i downgrade jackson on my pom to 1.9.12 i get JSON data. what i dont understand now is why it doesnt work with the latest version of jackson 2.2.2 (i use com.fasterxml.jackson.core jackson-jaxrs-json-provider jackson-core jackson-databind jackson-annotations

Comment: OK i understand now with jackson 2.2.2 i have to use CXF in version 2.7.6-SNAPSHOT in order to get json data. I was once again very inspired using latest version of libraries ;) thank you @Avi without your post i didnt have the idea of downgrading